# how to match chart data points with chart data points in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, series, linq.js

I am trying to remove data points from a chart series. the series is a array of arrays. I need to loop through it with javascript or linq.js, find the correct one and remove it from the series. I have tried some different methods but I am stuck.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt6p40o5/)

```
var customSeriesSums = [{
"style":"smooth",
"color":"blue",
"data":[
    [600,30000],
    [800,60000],
    [1100,100000]
],
"name":"Subject Property",
"removeByNames":[
    ["Product1"],
    ["Product2"],
    ["Product3"]
],
"$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]

var sqft = 800;
var price = 60000;
```

I need to match up the sqft and price values with a array inside data. the first value in the arrays are sqft, price. I will be removing the matching item from the data array. I will be working with a single object such as my post. here is what the end result needs to look like.

```
var customSeriesSums = [{
"style":"smooth",
"color":"blue",
"data":[
    [600,30000]
    [1100,100000]
],
"name":"Subject Property",
"removeByNames":[
    ["Product1"],
    ["Product2"],
    ["Product3"]
],
"$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, hopefully you get it answered

Comment: _What_ are you removing, items from the `data` array?  Only from the first result object?  Are you removing or are you filtering?  You need to be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish.  Your code snippet tells us nothing.

Comment: sorry about that, see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and if both your conditions are met remove that element. Is this what you are trying for?

```
   var customSeriesSums = [{
    "style":"smooth",
    "color":"blue",
    "data":[
        [600,30000],
        [800,60000],
        [1100,100000]
    ],
    "name":"Subject Property",
    "removeByNames":[
        ["Product1"],
        ["Product2"],
        ["Product3"]
    ],
    "$$hashKey":"object:30"
}]

    var sqft = 800;
    var price = 60000;
    var i=0;
    customSeriesSums[0].data.forEach(function(sums){
    if(sums[0] == sqft && sums[1] == price)
         customSeriesSums[0].data.splice(i, 1);
     i++;   
    });
    console.log(customSeriesSums);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nt6p40o5/2/